# 404 NOT FOUND error Magento installation process

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento, magento2

I'am trying to install magento 2.4 on ubuntu 20.04

I've installed magento with composer.

mysql and apach are running fine and php installed correctly as shown below

All magento commands are working fine so I think magento is working.
But when I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/` I get 404 not found as shown below

I think maybe the problem is with the configs of php and apache

This is my magento config file

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.conf
```

[image]

mysql and apach are running fine and php installed correctly:
[image]

magento2 directory

[image]

The problem is wen I try to get the magento url, I get this error

[image]

**UPDATED1 :**

```
http://127.0.0.1/
```

[image]

Comment: You have your root set to `magento2`, so you shouldn't need it in the URL.

Comment: I updated and added the screenshot for that url

Comment: Run `apachectl -S`, double-check what it says. I'm going to guess that you have a conflict between the default configuration and your magento. You can try `http://localhost`, since that's what you have for your ServerName, but that may also conflict with the default.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and [help/on-topic]: I see nothing related to _programming_ (which is stackoverflow's focus).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like magento 2.4 not support web based installation.check this [link](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/system/tools.html)
[image]

here are what I recommend for you :

1. you must install magento 2.4 from command line
2. make sure you install elasticsearch, and another system requirement, you can check this [link](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html)

if you have install all the requirement system, follow this step :

1. add magento.local to your /etc/hosts
   [image]
2. change your apache virtual host like below (make sure change the magento path) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName magento.local

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/magento/
   
   <Directory /var/www/magento/>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

3. enable vhost and apache rewrite : `sudo a2ensite magento && sudo a2enmod rewrite`
4. restart apache : `sudo systemctl restart apache2`
5. Install magento using command line :

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://magento.local/ \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=db_name \
--db-user=db_user \
--db-password=db_pass \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 \
--elasticsearch-host=localhost \
--elasticsearch-port=9200 \
--elasticsearch-index-prefix=magento2 \
--elasticsearch-timeout=15
```

6. verify the installation, visit : http://magento.local in browser

Hope this help you.